# TwitteR: issue when trying to use getFollowers() or getFriends()

Tags: r, twitter, rcurl

This is probably a very basic question, however, I spent so much time trying to figure it out and simply cannot come up with a solution.

I have been trying to get data from Twitter on users' friends and followers using TwitteR. I used this simple syntax:

```
user_test<-getUser('WorldBank') 

user_test_n<-user_test$getScreenName()

following<-user_test$getFollowers(n=50)
```

I receive this message after running the last line:

```
Error in split.default(users, ceiling(seq_along(users)/100)) : 
  first argument must be a vector
```

The same problem occurs when I attempt to extract friends from Twitter. The syntax seems quite straightforward - what can be the issue?

Thank you!

Lucie

Comment: There's a bug in the production version which is fixed on github. I hope to push a new version to cran soon